# Looping UIImage Fade Transition with Multiple Images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a viewController where a UIImageView transitions between different images every 10 seconds. This works well until I try to add more than two images. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I get the error: "No known class method for selector 'imageNamed::'

These are my methods:

**viewDidLoad with a timer:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    i = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self 
    selector:@selector(swapImage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

**Here is the code that works with two images:**

```
- (void)swapImage {

    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:(i % 2) ? @"authBg1.png" : @"authBg2.png"];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.0f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction 
    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [background.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    i++;
}
```

**If I change the first background.image line to add a new image, I get the error:**

```
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:(i % 3) ? @"authBg1.png" : @"authBg2.png" : 
@"authBg3.png"];
```

Any ideas as to why this might not be working? Thanks!

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, `UIImage` has a builtin way to animate through an array of images: `background.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"authBg1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"authBg2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"authBg3.png"], nil]; background.animationRepeatCount = 0; background.animationDuration = 10; [background startAnimating];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary operator can only support 2 conditions unfortunately.

If you need more then 2 conditions use if statements.

---

If/else

```
if(i%2 == 0){

}elseif(i%3==0){

}else{

}
```

But if you really want ternary you can nest them though its harder to read

```
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:(i % 2) ? @"authBg1.png" : (i % 3) ?@"authBg3.png" : @"authBg2.png"];
```

Comment: Thanks! Could I still have it loop with an if statement? I guess divide by three and if is multiple of three, something like that would work right?

Comment: Yes thats fine , ternary is either true or false it wont let you add more, so add as many modulo conditions as you need in the ifelse

Comment: Cool, I'll search for an example of how to combine module coniditions

Comment: Sorry for the horrible formatting im kn my phone ;)

Comment: Please don’t nest ternaries. Think of the children :-P

Comment: I recommend a switch statement. It’s perfect for dealing with the outcome of a small `%` operation.